# What does ++num1var[num2var] mean?

Tags: awk

Page 109 of `The AWK Programming Language` book has a statement to create a 2-D array named `attr`:

```
attr[nrel, $1] = ++nattr[nrel]
```

`nrel` = an integer representing the number of relations (tables)

`nattr` = an integer representing the number of attributes (table columns)

Substituting `country` for `$1`, `1` for `nrel`, and `1` for `nattr` we have:

```
attr[1, country] = 1[1]
```

What does the right-hand side of that statement mean? It appears to be referencing subscript `1` of array `1`. Can an array be named `1`? Would you explain what that expression means, please?

Comment: `++nattr[nrel]` is a fatal error if `nattr` is an integer. Demo: https://ideone.com/DmTgSU

Comment: `nattr = an integer representing the number of attributes (table columns)` Where from do you have that? No it's not, it's an uninitialized array. `Substituting country for $1, 1 for nrel, and 1 for nattr we have:` So you have some assumptions, you used those assumptions and ended up with something invalid. That means that your assumptions that you started with are not valid. nattr is not an integer. `Can an array be named 1?` no. `what that expression means, please?` this expression is invalid, it doesn't mean anything.

Comment: That book is very old, out of date, and lacking in information. Get Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition by Arnold Robbins instead.

Comment: Regarding "a statement to create a 2-D array named attr" - `attr` in your code is a **pseudo**-2D array, to get an actual 2D array you'd need to use GNU awk and a different syntax, `attr[nrel][$1] =`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Page 109(...)

I have look into [`archive.org`'s version](https://archive.org/details/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/page/n119/mode/2up) and line

```
attr[nrel, $1] = ++nattr[nrel]
```

is sole line referencing `nattr` and therefore this is where `nattr` is created, as you are asking about value under key it will be array. You might check that by substituting all but `nattr` as proposed and using [`typeof` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Type-Functions.html)

```
awk 'BEGIN{attr[1, "France"] = ++nattr[1];print typeof(nattr)}' emptyfile
```

gives output

```
array
```

therefore shown line does firstly increase value in *array* `nattr` under *key* `nrel` and then assign such changed value to array `attr` under key `nrel, $1`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thank you @Daweo So I can have an array named 1? And I can reference its cells like this: 1[1]? And I can assign the value of 1[1] to another variable?

Comment: @RogerCostello `1` is not vaild variable name as *The name of a variable must be a sequence of letters, digits, or underscores, and it may not begin with a digit* if you want to know more read [Using Variables in The GNU Awk's User Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html)

Comment: what you say makes sense. But, but, but, what is 1[1] if it's not an array or variable?

Comment: @RogerCostello syntax error

Comment: Do you mean the code on page 109 of the AWK book is incorrect?

Comment: @RogerCostello no, `nattr` is holding array, `1[1]` is syntax error